# Override properties from Azure App Configuration Store

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, spring-cloud

**TL;DR**

How to have system properties on CLI or environment variables override properties that are provided by an Azure App Configuration Store? Or is this maybe not possible at all?

**Longer story**

Let us assume a property named `app.prop`. Let us further assume the following entry in `application.yml` or in `application-<profile>.yml`:

```
app:
    prop: Default
```

Usually, you are able to start the Spring Boot application and provide a system property (e.g. `-Dapp.prop=SYS`) or an environment variable (e.g. `export APP_PROP=ENV`) with the effect that the latter overrides the value of the YML config files. If you - for example - provided the environment variable, your application has the value `ENV` for the property `app.prop`.

When reading the same property from an Azure App Configuration Store, you can provide a system property or an environment variable as you like. But the value is not overridden anymore; it is the value that is stored in the Azure App Configuration Store.

Some code

I am using Spring Boot version 2.5.7:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.7</version>
</parent>
```

Further, I am using the following library for accessing the Azure App Configuration Store:

```
<properties>
    <azure-spring-cloud.version>2.7.0</azure-spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${azure-spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-spring-cloud-appconfiguration-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Additionally, for starting the application, I am providing the following property:

```
spring.cloud.azure.appconfiguration.stores[0].connection-string = ...
```

This all works very well. In the Azure App Configuration Store, I have the following property:

```
app.prop = Azure
```

If now starting the application with the following environment variable `APP_PROP = ENV`, the value of the property `app.prop` is still `Azure`, and not `ENV`.

Is there any setting missing, so that I can have the same behavior that I had without the above mentioned library?

Actually, I searched a lot, but did not find anything except for some statements regarding [overriding values of remote properties in the Spring Cloud documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#overriding-bootstrap-properties), which is not really my case (I am using Azure App Configuration Store).

Comment: How about `spring-cloud-config-client` & `spring.cloud.config.enabled=true`?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spring-cloud/how-to-prepare-app-deployment?pivots=programming-language-java

Comment: @MartinZeitler This is about Azure Spring Cloud, which is a resource where you can deploy your Spring Boot applications to and that already hosts a Spring Cloud Config Server. Unfortunately, we are not using that. We are using [Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview) for our Spring Boot deployments. And now we are trying to use [Azure App Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/overview) as an external config provider (which is a bit like a Spring Cloud Config server).

Comment: As I understand it, the one is configuration on deployment, and the other a config service. I've just thought, because the namespace is quite similar; it might still be worth an attempt.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I will try that out ... Actually, it seems as if the mentioned library (`azure-spring-cloud-appconfiguration-config`) itself depends on some Spring cloud dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole point of using Azure App Configuration is to store your config in one place and easily manage it without redeploying / restarting the app. Therefore I don't think this is should be even possible.

I would recommend to use labels to load specific version of your `prop` based on labels data. Few cases:

1. If you need this property only locally, don't specify it in App Configuration.
2. If you need multiple versions of it, then just create same property with multiple labels and use your `spring.profile` (or other conf-property) to distinguish the version.
3. If you need to load multiple versions of it, load multiple labels:
   As described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/spring-cloud-starter-appconfiguration-config-readme?view=azure-java-stable#load-from-multiple-labels

You can use this sample to see how it works:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/azure-spring-boot_3.6.0/sdk/appconfiguration/spring-cloud-starter-azure-appconfiguration-config

Comment: I guess, this is as far as I can get. Actually, we are using your option 1 for properties that we _also_ need locally, mainly logging settings. And we are using the labels heavily with multiple profiles.

Comment: Hi @MrPatience, the statement "The whole point of using Azure App Configuration is to store your config in one place" isn't always true.  E.g., sometimes systems use Azure App Configuration so that certain settings can be shared between multiple apps while other settings are not shared centrally.  Thus, it makes sense to be able to combine multiple config providers (as dotnet allows natively).  Integration tests are another example of when one might want to combine config providers or override the values in Azure App Config.